# Dockerfile windows questions about "RUN"

Tags: windows, powershell, dockerfile

I am trying to write docekerfile for windows that uses powershell scripts. The code in question is:

```
ARG BASE_PATH=c:\\TEMP

WORKDIR ${BASE_PATH}

ARG MINGW32_SCRIPT=install_python.ps1
ARG MINGW32_INSTALLER=mingw-get-0.6.2-mingw32-beta-20131004-1-bin.zip
ADD ${MINGW32_SCRIPT} ${BASE_PATH}\\${MINGW32_SCRIPT} 
COPY ${MINGW32_INSTALLER} ${BASE_PATH}\\${MINGW32_INSTALLER}

RUN powershell -command "./%MINGW32_SCRIPT%"
```

How can I use return value from %MINGW32_SCRIPT% to fail the build if the script fails?

Note:

I tried to set

```
SHELL ["powershell", "-command"]

...

RUN ${MINGW32_SCRIPT}
```

but that seems not to work? Whats wrong? It fails because:

./${MINGW32_SCRIPT} : The term './${MINGW32_SCRIPT}' is not recognized as ....

Comment: You're trying to write a docker file that uses a powershell script to install python to run shell scripts? Seems somewhat convoluted. As for your question the answer is right there? Did you try to tun that command on your local machine?

Comment: @Seth The purpose of the powershell scripts is to setup c++ developement environment on windows machines. 
The same scripts can be used to create docker image to run CI/CD pipelines. 
I believed I tried all commands on local machine, but I might have missed it. 
Can you be more specific? (I will retry them.) But I do now know how that answers the question how to make the build fail. (I found the answer anyway.)

Comment: Update: In order to fail the build all that is needed is to 
```throw "some error"``` from the script.

Comment: The error message told you that `${MINGW32_SCRIPT}` seemingly isn't being resolved but rather used as a literal. Don't forget that you can answer your own questions and mark is as answered as well.